# In Swift or Objective-C, having a NSData object, is there a way to determine programmatically the NSData.ReadingOptions used to create it?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch

In Swift, let's consider this line of code:

```swift
let data = try Data.init(contentsOf: url, options:NSData.ReadingOptions.alwaysMapped)
```

Is there a chance, at a later stage, to retrieve programmatically the NSData.ReadingOptions value used to instantiate the object ? Thanks

Comment: For `Data` — probably not, but for `NSData` constructor won't return you object of `NSData` type directly, but subtype or some other type with common interface (`Objective C`/`Foundation` is weird in that way). So you may check which types are returned depending on `options`, and determine using type matching.

Comment: I've checked and it would be either `NSConcreteData` for uncached, or `OS_dispatch_data` for mapped contents of the file.

Comment: Why do you need that information?

Comment: user28434 - thanks a lot for your answer. I am trying to check its consistency when determining at a later stage and not immediately after instantiation. For Martin: I am writing unit tests for an existing code base. The data objects in the source should be always mapped, but I want to be certain of that via a programmatic check.